# Django: Getting a reverse error, but data still goes through the database

Tags: django, python-3.x

I'm getting a reverse error when redirecting to the details page after filling out the form (and the information actually going to my db). I'm not sure how to fix it since it was working before, so it must've somehow broke in the middle while coding.

The error that I'm getting :

`NoReverseMatch at /finches/create/
Reverse for 'finches_detail' with keyword arguments '{'pk': 20}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['finches/(?P<finch_id>[0-9]+)/$']`

Here's part of my models.py:

```
class Finch(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    breed = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=250)
    age = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    toys = models.ManyToManyField(Toy)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('finches_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.id})
```

It should return /finches/ upon creation, but it doesn't.

My views.py class and function:

```
    finch = Finch.objects.get(id=finch_id)
    toys_finch_doesnt_have = Toy.objects.exclude(
        id__in=finch.toys.all().values_list('id'))
    feeding_form = FeedingForm()
    return render(request, 'main_app/finch_detail.html', {
        'finch': finch,
        'feeding_form': feeding_form,
        'toys': toys_finch_doesnt_have
    })


class FinchCreate(CreateView):
    model = Finch
    fields = ['name', 'breed', 'description', 'age']
```

and the urls.py

```
    path('finches/<int:finch_id>/', views.finch_detail, name='finches_detail'),
    path('finches/create/',
         views.FinchCreate.as_view(), name="finches_create"),
```

I'll update more info if it's needed. Upon creating,

I notice that the link is still at finches/create even pressing submit. Any ideas on what's happening or any solutions?

Thanks

Comment: `finches_details` takes `finch_id` argument, and in your `reverse` call you're passing `pk` argument. The data goes to the database regardless of the error is because Django by default uses autocommit.

Comment: No idea how I missed that. Thanks!